# Android - Media Content Observer Triggers Multiple Times

Tags: android, image, contentobserver

I've made some `ContentObservers` that listen for new images. But every time I take a picture, the observer gets triggered 4 times. When I get the `onChange` trigger, I query the ContentResolver for the image data, but I noticed a weird thing. The first time `onChange` triggers, the image I get from the ContentResolver is ~70 bytes smaller than the subsequent 3 times. Does anyone know why that is? Also, is there a good check I can perform to consolidate these 4 `onChange` triggers into 1?